# Slack Button text is not fully shown. dots are added at end

Tags: botframework, slack, botkit

[slack button getting cut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvIbR.png)

```
bot.reply(message, {
    attachments:[
        {
            title: 'Do you want to interact with my buttons?',
            callback_id: '123',
            attachment_type: 'default',
            actions: [
                {
                    "name":"yes",
                    "text": "Yes",
                    "value": "yes",
                    "type": "button",
                },
                {
                    "name":"no",
                    "text": "No",
                    "value": "no",
                    "type": "button",
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
});
```

> If text length is more, Button gets wrapped up with fewer text and rest ends up as ... I got stuck here. Please help to show full text in button.

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature of Slack, not of BotFramework nor of Botkit. The Slack interface simply doesn't allow long button titles. I don't know what the character length limit is, but you appear to be hitting it and it is truncating the text and replacing it with an ellipses.

I would recommend you reach out to Slack via their developer support page, located [here](https://api.slack.com/support), to identify any possible workarounds or solutions.